# How to check result mp4's integrity?

Tags: ffmpeg, verify, integrity

There are 4 categories, each Categories has 10 mp4 files.

I used ffmpeg to concatenate 4 categories, such as cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat4.

With simple calculation, I get 10000 concatenated mp4 files.

Here is the problem. There are some mp4 files among the 10000 files that are wrongly encoded. So I can't play the files. I found 100 files so far.

Is there any options that I can check the concatenated mp4 is correctly encoded? Or can I verify all of them without playing?

I've searched Stack Overflow and seen ffmpeg's options but I'm not used to ffmpeg and it looks it'd take super long but I got no much time.

Comment: Why not [do a web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mp4+verify+format)? The first result at superuser.com looks useful.

Comment: Check this https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4

Comment: I saw the superuser and tried the command but it didn't work yesterday.. I tried it today again and it worked... Maybe I typed wrong...Sorry for bothering you...Anyway thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encoded 10000 mp4 files from 40 source mp4 files.

In conclusion,

I used this command.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i ./result/$num.mp4 -preset ultrafast -f null - 2>> check.log
```

where $num is from 0000 to 9999.

To check the integrity,

use "-v error" option.